# Pass urls stored in array to window.open in for loop - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to step through an array and pass my urls stored there to the window.open function. This is what I have.

```
$('a.linked').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var i;
    var urls = ['http://example.com', 'http://example2.com', 'http://example3.com'];

    for (i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
      var ts = i*3500;
      setTimeout(function(){window.open(urls[i]); }, ts);
  }
});
```

This is opening the new windows at the correct timing but I'm getting about:blank. I thought it might be not escaping quotes.

> The duplicate answer says I'm losing my value of `i` However, when I remove the setTimeout I get all the new windows with the
>   correct urls. The following code demonstrates not losing the value of i.

```
$('a.linkedinProfiles').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var i;
    var urls = ['http://example.com', 'http://example2.com', 'http://example3.com'];
    for (i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
    var ts = i*3500;
    {window.open(urls[i]); };   
    } });
```

I know this has to be something simple I am missing. Thanks in advance.

Comment: a few things are wrong here: don't defer opening the windows - they have to be open with a click in the stack. also you are losing the value for `i`.

Comment: you need to use fully qualified URLs - including protocol  (e.g. `http://example.com`).

Comment: i just threw 'abc.com' to shorten the code im using FQDN

Answer (score 0):

May not be the full solution, but you could try adding "http://" to the beginning of your URLs. Currently they will be opened as relative links.

Comment: sorry the urls in the example were shortened and I forgot to add http://